# Zero divisor conjecture and idempotent conjecture

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, oa.operator-algebras

Let $G$ be a torsion-free group and $C$ the ring of complex numbers. The zero divisor (idempotent, resp.) conjecture is that there is no nontrivial zerodivisor (idempotent, resp.) in $CG$. 
The wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring
says "This conjecture (zero divisor conjecture) is equivalent to K[G] having no non-trivial idempotents under the same hypotheses for K and G.
"

Is this obvious true? Are there some reference for this claim?

Comment: According to T.Y.Lam, "The first course in noncommutative rings", p.95, for a torsion-free group $G$ and a domain $k$, the following properties are equivalent: (6.17) $kG$ is reduced, (6.18) $kG$ is a domain (conjectured to be always true). So I think that it should have been "nilpotents" in place of "idempotents".

Comment: The equivalence of zerodivisor and nilpotent is already known in D. Passmann's book. Probably, the wiki page is making a mistake.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Passman showed that whenever there are zero-divisors in a group ring one also has (non-zero) nilpotent elements. He shows that for any field $k$ and any torsionfree group $G$, the ring $kG$ is a prime ring, i.e. the zero-ideal is a prime ideal.

Now, if $a,b \in kG$ are non-zero and $ab=0$, then there exists $c \in kG$ such that $bca\neq 0$. (This is just another way of saying that the product of the two-sided ideal $(b)$ with the two-sided ideal $(a)$ cannot give the zero ideal, since $(0)$ is a prime ideal.)

Now, we see that $(bca)^2 = bcabca =0$. Hence, $kG$ contains nilpotent elements. The other direction is obvious.

Comment: You say: "The other direction is obvious". The question asked about a possible equivalence between zero divisor conjecture and idempotent conjecture. How does existence of non-trivial nilpotents imply existence of non-trivial idempotents (elements $e$ other than $0,1$ satisfying $e^2=e$)?

Comment: I was thinking about the other direction of my claim about zero-divisors and nilpotent elements. In fact I was just explaining some detail of Passman's argument that you mentioned already in your comment.

Answer (score 14):

Clearly one implies the other as $x^2=x$ means $x(x-1)=0$.

I doubt they are known to be equivalent since the sources I found: the [K-theory handbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=Xxg3L20qMeUC&lpg=PA729&ots=Qh-rf2oFpR&dq=Kadison%20idempotent%20conjecture%20and%20Kaplansky%20zero%20divisor%20conjecture%20are%20equivalent&pg=PA729#v=onepage&q=Kadison%20idempotent%20conjecture%20and%20Kaplansky%20zero%20divisor%20conjecture%20are%20equivalent&f=false) and Alain Valette [survey](http://www.math.ohio-state.edu/~indira/Valette.pdf) (see Conjecture 2) listed them as separate conjectures. Of course, it would be hard to prove they are *not* equivalent, since both might be true!

Answer (score 1):

The zero divisor conjecture implies the idempotent conjecture as $1$ and $0$ are the only idempotents in a ring with unity and no zero-divisors, nothing sure about the other way around