# Invertible elements in a group algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, group-rings

Let $H$ be a torsion-free abelian group and let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field with two elements. 
I would like to ask the following question:

Is the group of units of the group algebra $\mathbb{K}[H]$ isomorphic to $H$ ?

Comment: No, obviously not, because $\mathbb{K}^\times \leq (\mathbb{K}[H])^\times$.

Comment: oops thanks, I will change my question.

Comment: Are we assuming $H$ to be finitely generated or not necessarily? In the finitely generated case the answer is yes.

Comment: @YonatanHarpaz No, I'm not assuming that H is finitely generated.

Comment: I just realized it doesn't matter. If $x \in \mathbb{K}[H]$ is invertible then there exists a finitely generated subgroup $H' \subseteq H$ such that $\mathbb{K}[H'] \subseteq \mathbb{K}[H]$ contains both $x$ and $x^{-1}$, and so we may as well assume that $H$ is finitely generated. The answer hence is yes.

Comment: It's indeed a classical conjecture of Kaplansky (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplansky%27s_conjecture) that if $K$ is a field , the units of $KG$ are the multiples of elements in the standard basis, and is well-known and easy when $G$ is abelian. In particular if $K$ has 2 elements, the obvious homomorphism $G\to KG^\times$ is an isomorphism (which is the right statement, just saying that they are isomorphic is weaker and much less interesting).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544093/, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79702/